# Get params from URI (edit admin grid form) exists but returns empty values

Tags: grid, edit, parameter

My URI when I click edit on any admin grid rows

> http://localhost/magento_1.11/index.php/admin/index/edit/entitiy_id/2/key/012d8de26b4b3f5718c3d5267cdd6c97dfba9f67ebc2c75774a632c4887d833c/

And in my edit action I am trying to access it with

```
$id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');

echo $id; // returns empty :(
```

But it is returning empty values always, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a grammar mistake:

```
entitiy_id/2
```

it should be

```
entity_id/2
```

Comment: oh my bad ...i got -1 .. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
```

inside your controller?